# get column value in _prepareColumns()

Tags: magento-1, grid

I have a custom grid in my custom backend module.

```
$this->addColumn('quota_item_id', array(
    'header' => $helper->__('quota_item_id@sales_flat_quota_item'),
    'align' => 'left',
    'width' => '10%',
    'index' => 'quota_item_id',
));

$this->addColumn('Actions', array(

    'header' => $helper->__('Actions'),
    'align' => 'left',
    'width' => '10%',
    'index' => 'quota_item_id',
    'type' => 'action',
    'getter' => 'getQuota_item_id',
    'actions' => array(
        array(
            'caption' => 'check order',
            'url' => 'javascript:void(0)',
            'field' => 'id',
            'href' => "javascript:void(0)",
            'target' => '_blank',
            'class' => 'checkOrder',
            'id' =>                       // how to get quota_item_id here?
        )
    ),
));
```

The id attribute, I want to assign `quota_item_id` to it, anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: you cannot get the id if a certain element in the grid in here.  
The code you mentioned is just the definition of a certain column in the grid.  
What exactly are your trying to achieve. Explain the feature you are implementing, maybe there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: @marius the quota_item_id is in the same collection which from a custom table. It really no hope to get the value of another column?

Comment: why do you need the value of that column? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: i want the action link  pass the  quota_item_id to a function via ajax, to process to other application.

Comment: it seems something like getter can do that, but in above code has no effect

Comment: getter is only useful in case of url for column type "action"

Comment: easy solution is make your own column renderer

Comment: @minesh patel any example?

Comment: check [this example](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/)  for custom column renderer